# The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s)

Tags: java, sorting, if-statement, merge

I'm trying to get this merge sort method done but for some reason I am shown an error "The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T"

for the if statement

```
if(a[beginHalf1] <= a[beginHalf2])
      {

        tempArray[index] = a[beginHalf1];
        beginHalf1++;
      }
```

here is the full code

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    void merge(T[] a, T[] tempArray, int first, int mid, int last){


           int beginHalf1 = first;
           int endHalf1 = mid;
           int beginHalf2 = mid +1;
           int endHalf2 = last;
           int index = 0;

    while((beginHalf1 <= endHalf1) && (beginHalf2 <= endHalf2) )
          {

           if(a[beginHalf1] <= a[beginHalf2]){

           tempArray[index] = a[beginHalf1];
           beginHalf1++;
        }

        else
        {
            tempArray[index]=a[beginHalf2];
            beginHalf2++;
        }
     index++;
    }




    } // end merge
```

Comment: Please add a language tag (Java?) to your question. And indent the code so it's more readable.

Comment: Another question in my textbook there is a line of code that says "Exchange a[indexFromLeft] and a[indexFromRight]" I know that "and" means && but what does "Exchange" mean?

Comment: *but what does "Exchange" mean?* -  switch? Are you sure `and` means `&&` in that line? Because `&&` is usually defined as `AND`.

Comment: "Exchange" means replace each one with the other. "and" in this case just has its normal English meaning, it has nothing to do with the logical operation `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

Operators >=< are for primitive types. You should use compareTo for T (if it's comparable).

```
if(a[beginHalf1].compareTo(a[beginHalf2]) <= 0)
```

Comment: Another question in my textbook there is a line of code that says "Exchange a[indexFromLeft] and a[indexFromRight]" I know that "and" means && but what does "Exchange" mean?